# How to convert HFS+ partition to APFS on Mac?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, hfs, apfs

After struggling with deleting Ubuntu from my Mac alongside with macOS, after deleting EFI volume it became free and unused. How can I convert it to APFS again and include that in my HD storage?

Disk structure:

[image: screenshot - disk structure]

Comment: That picture is not drawn to scale. 313MB is only 1/1000 (one-tenth of 1%) of your 251 GB drive. It's probably not worth the hassle. If this is your main internal boot drive, you might want to leave it like this so you can easily put the EFI system partition back in case you need it for a future system update.

Comment: You were right. My efforts somehow led to damaging the volumes so I had to reinstall macos and backup. Thank you though :)

Comment: Paragon should have let you delete the last partition, moved the three small ones to the end, then extended the first container. [Not to be attempted without a backup]

Comment: Actually Paragon only erased the partition, but I didn’t manage to put that as part of my Macintosh HD. Don’t know why